# Htaccess rewrite Single, or multiple $_GET parameter on LINUX base server

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, get

Below's url is I need .htaccess rewrite from ?view=home to /view/home

```
http://example.com/?view=home
```

And what if my url is quite dynamic with $_GET Parameter that have multiple $_GET?

```
http://example.com/?view=home&url=this&name=test&id=that
```

I had try few rewrite module but cant get result that I wanted.
Below is my rewrite engine :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# specific rule
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^=]+)=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^(constant)$ /index.php?view$1 [L]

# general catch-all
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

My current web hosting is on Linux Web Hosting, locally running my tested file is on XAMPP environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can this code to redirect from `?view=home` to `/view/home`:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?([^=]+)=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?$1=$2 [L,QSA]

# specific rule
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^=]+)=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^(constant)$ /index.php?view$1 [L]

# general catch-all
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer,but I'm currently geting an internal server error when use ur .htaccess code.
does above htaccess work on
example.net?view=testing
or example.net/test/view=testing
or example.net/test/index.php?view=testing

Am trying on this website http://seo-website-designer.com/HtAccess-301-Redirect-Generator , but had no clue on it.

Comment: This works with `http://localhost/?view=testing` (see updated code) I retested and it is not causing 500

Comment: Thanks its work! Seems like my server's setup causes when i place 'Options +FollowSymlinks' on htaccess i will get 500 internal server error, but i removed it, everything work smooth and charm! Thanks @anubhava

Comment: Hi, another question what If , my $_GET parameter is always dynamic and always have different key?just like

`http://localhost/?key1=testing`
`http://localhost/?key2=testing`
`http://localhost/?key3=testing&key2=testing`

htaccess can't rewrite dynamically right?Need rewrite by us manually?

Comment: `http://localhost/?key2=testing` is easy to handle but if you variable length parameters like `http://localhost/?key3=testing&key2=testing&foo=bar&id=1234` then rule will be more tricky. For now I have made an edit to take care of first case.